# Route53 DNS not Resolving when set up with Shopify Store

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, shopify, amazon-route53, custom-domain

I have a domain registered with Route53 (AWS). I'm trying to connect it as my Custom Domain on a Shopify store.

I update the A record and the CNAME record with the following values.

- @, A, 23.227.38.65
- www, CNAME, shops.myshopify.com

Despite setting these records up and going through the domain verification settings in Shopify, I'm unable to get the DNS to properly resolve and direct traffic to my Shopify store. Instead, the browser always just says:

`server IP address could not be found.`

Is there something I'm missing on the AWS/Route53 side? It's in a Public Hosted Zone, so I don't believe I need to create any inbound VPC rules or security group configurations.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

RESOLVED.

In the Name servers settings of the domain, I had to update them to the same NS records that Route53 had generated within the DNS settings. Once done everything started working after a few minutes.

Comment: If you perform a DIG lookup on your domain does it return these expected values?

Comment: Hey Chris - no the DIG lookup doesn't return these values.  

```
opcode QUERY
rcode SERVFAIL
```

Comment: Does the DIG lookup return your Route 53 nameservers?

Comment: @ChrisWilliams this is the response I get for the NS record...

```
id 55621
opcode QUERY
rcode SERVFAIL
flags QR RD RA
;QUESTION
www.<MYDOMAIN>.com. IN NS
;ANSWER
;AUTHORITY
;ADDITIONAL
```

Comment: OK, who is the registrar for your hostname? :) This is a nameserver configuration issue, so likely invalid or mssing nameserver configuration for your hostname

Comment: Route53, I transferred it to them last month from ExactHosting.

Comment: OK if you go to the public hosted zone and copy all 4 values of your NS record, then in your domains edit the name server options to be these 4 values. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-name-servers-glue-records.html

Comment: I went ahead and made that change and will let you know if it resolves!

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for the help @ChrisWilliams

Comment: I have added this as the answer

Comment: @SebastianScholl - Where did you make these changes? I am having a similar problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77056180/using-route53-registered-domain-with-shopify-online-store

Comment: @ChrisWilliams has the correct solution!

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by the domain not having its matching name servers configured within Route 53.

The OP had migrated his domain to Route 53 and setup a public hosted zone in Route 53, however the connection between the 2 had not been made.

To resolve this take all the values from the `NS` record of the public hosted zone and add them to the Nameservers configuration in Route 53.

Take a look at the [Adding or changing name servers and glue records for a domain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-name-servers-glue-records.html) page for further step on this action.