# Using Route53 registered domain with Shopify online store

Tags: shopify, alias, amazon-route53, cname

I bought a domain from AWS through Route53. I am trying to link my shopify store with this domain. I tried the following configs from shopify,

1. Added a new `CNAME` record with name = `www`.mydomain.com, and value
   = `shops.myshopify.com`.
2. Added a new Alias `A` record to route 53 with `@` name and value = `MyStoreIPAddress`.

When I verify my configs over on Shopify, I see this error,
[image]

I tried following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63510449/route53-dns-not-resolving-when-set-up-with-shopify-store) but I am not really sure where should I copy the `NS records` values? Since I bought the domain from route53, I am assuming that correct values already exist for DoNS settings. I also noticed that route53 propagation happens really fast so I dont need to wait for 48 hours to see the propagation results. My store still isnt linked properly. Can anyone please provide some pointers? Thank you!